# Cmake configure fails

Tags: cmake

When I execute

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$KF5 .
```

I get this error:

```
Make Error at //share/cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.cmake:229 (file):
  file RELATIVE_PATH must be passed a full path to the file:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:117 (configure_package_config_file)
```

Any hint?

Comment: What is value of `KF5` environment variable, which you use for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`? If this is relative path, make it absolute. BTW, error message tell about similar things: call for `configure_package_config_file` at `CMakeLists.txt:117` uses some improper parameters, which are detected inside that function.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly your environment variables aren't setup properly. Please ensure that the KF5 variable is set appropriately.

Please follow instructions at : https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source#Run_kdesrc-build

Finally, don't forget to "source" these variables in your current session after setting them. Output of the command "env" will help you check the values contained in your environment variables. Will give you enough pointers to fix this.